# Хранение домашних каталогов нескольких пользователей в одном репозитории

Tags: git

Имею такую струкртуру каталогов:

```
home
  /user1
  /user2
```

В папке home у меня инициализирован git.

Поскольку я работаю в директории /home из-под пользователей user1 и user2, мне приходится постоянно пользоваться git из под sudo. Как можно избежать этого без необходимости создавать два разных проекта под пользователя user1 и user2?

Comment: Что вам мешает положить проект в любую папку на которую у вас полные права, чтобы не мучаться с sudo?

Comment: У меня фронтенд и бэкенд разделен на два разных пользователя в целях безопасности.

Comment: Фронтенд и бэкенд должны быть в двух разных репозиториях гита. Это же реально разный код, разве нет?

Comment: а когда вы находитесь под user1 то доступна репа user2 ?

Comment: Он то должен быть на двух, но так я буду тратить время на синхронизацию двух разных репозиториев, а я лучше потрачу его на разработку. Когда я нахожусь в user1 то могу  ходить по сайту везде, если user2(фронтенд) то заперт в своей директории через sftp. Вышел из положения прописав alias sgit=sudo git и еще отдельный для изменения прав на папки и файлы, который вызываю после того, как заливаю изменения на рабочий сервер. Вроде вышло не сильно затратно, главное что экономлю время и не парюсь с разделением репозиториев.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> поскольку я работаю в директории /home из под пользователей user1 и user2 мне приходиться постоянно пользоваться git из под sudo. Как можно избежать этого без необходимости создавать два разных проекта под пользователя user1 и user2?

1. насколько мне известно, ни одна из существующих *vcs* не умеет «из коробки» сохранять в репозитории информацию о принадлежности файлов/каталогов. требуется либо какая-то «надстройка», либо (полу-)ручное вмешательство.
2. даже если такую информацию сохранить, то её применение невозможно от имени рядового пользователя: у него просто нет прав (как минимум) на создание файлов/каталогов, принадлежащих другому пользователю.

поэтому для описанной вами ситуации самое, на мой взгляд, разумное — создать по отдельному репозиторию (или по отдельной ветке в одном репозитории) для хранения домашнего каталога каждого из пользователей.

---

из «надстроек» можно упомянуть etckeeper (одноимённые пакеты входят, насколько мне известно, в репозитории всех популярных дистрибутивов). эта программа, конечно, «заточена» под управление каталогом `/etc`, но, согласно документации, в принципе, можно управлять и другими каталогами. впрочем, её тоже потребуется запускать от имени *root*-а (см. пункт 2 выше).